# shell_exec php example

Tags: php, multithreading, shell-exec

Hi there are multiple specific examples but I just wanted to have a working generic calling PHP into background example from shell_exec.

So my php function runs a large processing job.

On the top of the script (process.php) I put?

```
!#usr/bin/php
```

i think - any way to get that specific path, maybe 'which php'?

then the actual command is

```
shell_exec(sprintf('php process.php %s %s > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &','data1','data2'));
```

and access the data from process.php with `argsv[1]` and `argsv[2]`

?

thanks

Comment: The shebang syntax is `#!/path/to/interpreter`, not `!#` as you had it, and yes, using `which php` will get the path you should use in the script. However, the shebang's only necessary if you're planning to run this directly on the command line, ie `./nameofscript`. If you're using the `php nameofscript.php` it's redundant,a s you're already running PHP explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely access the arguments from process.php the way you described, but why would you want to kick off process.php like that?

If you're already in a php shell script, why not just include the process.php file?

Comment: it's not accessing the other script?

Is there a way to run a local function via the shell_exec?

Comment: From within any php script executed from the command line, or via shell_exec, you can access the arguments with the argv array.  Instead of executing another php script with shell_exec though, why not use an include statement, such as include('process.php');?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run [curl multi exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php) on your php script with a parameter and receive an answer after run, like: `http://localhost/phpjob.php?par1=asdasd&par2=1212....`